# Possible to set fill level below value for Gtk::Scale?

Tags: user-interface, gtk, gtkmm

While it's strightforward to set the fill level above the Scale's value using `set_fill_level` setting the fill level below the Scale's value does not appear to work.

To clarify I'd like to, for instance, be able to set the fill level to 25% while the slider is at 50%

```
FFFF----S-------
```

- Am I missing something obvious?

or alternately:

- Does anyone know of a clever hack to get this to work?

Extra details:

- libgtk2.0-dev
- libgtkmm-2.4-dev
- Ubuntu 10.04.4
- default theme (Ambience)

Images of the undesired behavior:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to disable the restriction:

> Additionally, it's possible to restrict the range's slider position to values which are smaller than the fill level. This is controller *[sic]* by [`gtk_range_set_restrict_to_fill_level()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkRange.html#gtk-range-set-restrict-to-fill-level) and is by default enabled.

([Source](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkRange.html#gtk-range-set-fill-level))

**Update:** Example:

[image: GtkHScale with fill-level=3 and value=5]

```py
import gtk

s = gtk.HScale()
s.set_show_fill_level(True)
s.set_restrict_to_fill_level(False)  # <=====
s.set_range(0, 10)
s.set_fill_level(3)
s.set_value(5)

w = gtk.Window()
w.connect('destroy', lambda *x: gtk.main_quit())
w.add(s)
w.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

**Update 2:** The problem seen in your screenshot is most likely a bug in the GTK+ theme. Around half of the themes I tested (both with GTK+ 2 and 3) have this problem. For the record, my screenshot was taken with the Adwaita (GTK+ 3) theme.

Comment: That's actually the inverse of what I'm hoping to do. That affects the position of the slider itself. I'm looking to affect the appearance of the "fill level". I'll add some clarification to the question.

Comment: I don't see the difference; disabling restrict-to-fill-level causes the fill level to be independent from the value, so it should allow what you're trying to do.

Comment: Without fill level, min to current value is drawn "filled" so with fill level enabled, if you pass the fill level there is no longer a distinction between fill level and the fill from the current position.

Comment: I'm still not sure I follow. Could you check the Update section and see if it matches what you're trying to do?

Comment: Strange. If I run the same code (with the edits I submitted) on my machine I get a different result. I wonder if it's a theme issue? What version of gtk are you running? (I''m using libgtk 2.0 and libgtkmm 2.4)

Comment: I've added screenshots. Thanks for the demo program btw, I should have done that myself to illustrate in the first place.

Comment: Yes, that would be a theme bug. I tested a bunch of GTK+ themes and quite a good number of them have the same issue. Some themes that work: Adwaita (gtk3), Crux (gtk2), Mint Z (gtk2,3). Most notably, Clearlooks (gtk2) has this bug.

Comment: If you update your answer with the theme bug info, I'll mark yours as the correct answer.